# cvs - connect to a Windows remote pserver: no such repository

Tags: cygwin, eclipse, cvs

I am with Windows 10 and Cygwin with cvs installed. I am trying to connect to a remote Windows CVS pserver to test. In spite of the fact that I can connect with Eclipse CVS client, I cannot connect with Cygwin command line. It says "No such repository".

What I have in Eclipse CVS setting are:

- username: my user name
- password: my password
- host: 10.99.64.39 (I guess it's internal)
- repo path: N:\CVSRepositorio\xxxxxx
- port: use default port

The command I use is:

```
cvs -d :pserver:username@10.99.64.39:2401/N:\\CVSRepositorio\\xxxxxx login
```

After entering my password, the error occurs.

Having changing `\\` to `/` and not working. I just don't see a possibility of mapping the Windows path to a UNIX-CVS recognisable form.

What is the problem?

Comment: I think the command you are trying is incorrect.
`cvs -d :pserver:username@10.99.64.39:2401:/CVSRepositorio/xxxxxx login`

Comment: `cvs -d :pserver:username@10.99.64.39:/CVSRepositorio/xxxxxx login` without port number

Comment: @TechieGossip so you mean N:/ is already included in the IP address? I don't get it. Make it an answer to elaborate, would you? Thanks.

Comment: N parameter is not required. You just make try with above commands

Comment: No, `N:\ ` is a Windows partition, not a parameter.... That's the problem.

Comment: You in N:\CVSRepositorio\xxx. First login to in cygwin. Cd to that path.. in command that should not be a local path. It must be a server path of CVS where repo is located

Comment: Thanks again, but that path with partition is the only information I have. I just want to know what ppl do if they want to connect with a Windows pserver? How they put the path to make CVS accept it? Can I map it in a UNIX form? Like /xxx/xxx/xxx?

Comment: This problem isn’t about the client, it’s about your server configuration. How did you set up the CVS server? Is it perhaps running from Cygwin?

Comment: That part is not clear yet. @DanielB I know what you are trying to do: `/cygdrive/N/...` right? I have tested and not working, so I guess: no.